# Cannot compile program on Windows 11 Pro due to pnet

Tags: windows, rust

I am writing a program, that I am in the process of porting to Windows.
It compiles fine on Arch Linux, but on Windows 11 Pro I get a cryptic error message (MRE):

```
PS C:\Users\Richard Neumann\packet_mre> cargo run
   Compiling memchr v2.5.0
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.66
   Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.11
   Compiling winapi v0.3.9
   Compiling libc v0.2.147
   Compiling no-std-net v0.6.0
   Compiling regex-syntax v0.7.4
   Compiling serde v1.0.183
   Compiling pnet v0.34.0
   Compiling pnet_base v0.34.0
   Compiling pnet_macros_support v0.34.0
   Compiling quote v1.0.32
   Compiling syn v2.0.28
   Compiling aho-corasick v1.0.2
   Compiling regex-automata v0.3.6
   Compiling pnet_sys v0.34.0
   Compiling ipnetwork v0.20.0
   Compiling pnet_datalink v0.34.0
   Compiling regex v1.9.3
   Compiling pnet_macros v0.34.0
   Compiling pnet_packet v0.34.0
   Compiling pnet_transport v0.34.0
   Compiling packet_mre v0.1.0 (C:\Users\Richard Neumann\packet_mre)
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181
  |
  = note: "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "C:\\Users\\RICHAR~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustcWG5SCh\\symbols.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.1jrl1f03chyke8d2.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.2dgdqdjrvzm9y86.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.2jrzp5tdslr8tno1.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.2vfiyjfl9i7si8kv.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.390d5w9r9o4r9g6d.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.3oq0b0yfd2ua2h2d.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.3uoiovk78t6bvgtg.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.3zq3f6k4q4bdi49u.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.46fjisleomhthckn.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.48e0gay90t3xyrfz.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.4rtab3eauu4vedrp.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.4xm91mbl41pkrfwu.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.4zd3td8eiz4fm8au.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.5gkksyr05430000r.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.civolclsa7fwc2k.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.fpms7awmn1zd3bz.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.ndxvf05a5a07vpx.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.qqkrkfwmrpy3ezx.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.v6ak64xgd8w1fu6.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.5qxchno6rthb1dl.rcgu.o" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\\pnet-0.34.0/lib/x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpnet-b16eda901aa5c202.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpnet_transport-8f49fda73c934eb2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpnet_packet-1b94417f21014e5c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpnet_macros_support-c54c33bceb31da39.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpnet_datalink-52328184a3b32753.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpnet_sys-56a97d69bb7989a3.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwinapi-f4432d3b48789b06.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblibc-4b2728a32b4c2fd3.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpnet_base-c323224a607ae713.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\libno_std_net-55d168852cc0ce5c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\libipnetwork-ae1a969f6db09c99.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\libserde-f249858e22f35b26.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd-391022a4250a8b9a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-3069c74fd845ecc2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_demangle-cae8325b8f11cb55.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd_detect-6ecbb4a24be3ec33.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libhashbrown-7cef55517a70b408.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libminiz_oxide-d1e72b1788c7e8f6.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libadler-65d80753bac4b1a6.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-932a6231bea08890.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libunwind-04ed514427316340.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcfg_if-9b75e26b1d0a074f.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liblibc-95c2795d82b7b742.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liballoc-1bf02ac2d8cdb80a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-117dfa1fe8688bcf.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcore-9ac5797c0b4842d0.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-ad271357e078d260.rlib" "iphlpapi.lib" "Packet.lib" "advapi32.lib" "cfgmgr32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib" "kernel32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "userenv.lib" "kernel32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "bcrypt.lib" "ntdll.lib" "msvcrt.lib" "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "/OUT:C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\packet_mre\\target\\debug\\deps\\packet_mre.exe" "/OPT:REF,NOICF" "/DEBUG" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\intrinsic.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\liballoc.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libcore.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\Richard Neumann\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libstd.natvis"
  = note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Packet.lib'


error: could not compile `packet_mre` (bin "packet_mre") due to previous error
PS C:\Users\Richard Neumann\packet_mre>
```

Searching for the error online yields suggestions to install an appropriate Windows SDK, but I have one installed and other programs I wrote in Rust compile and link without issues.

MRE:

`Cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "packet_mre"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
pnet = "0.34.0"
```

`src/main.rs`

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", discover_address_or_exit("0.0.0.0/0"));
}

#[must_use]
pub fn discover_address_or_exit(network: &str) -> std::net::IpAddr {
    discover_address(pnet::ipnetwork::IpNetwork::from_str(network).unwrap_or_else(|error| {
        eprintln!("{error}");
        std::process::exit(1)
    }))
    .unwrap_or_else(|| {
        eprintln!("No address found");
        std::process::exit(2);
    })
}

#[must_use]
pub fn discover_address(network: pnet::ipnetwork::IpNetwork) -> Option<std::net::IpAddr> {
    for iface in pnet::datalink::interfaces() {
        for ip in iface.ips {
            if network.contains(ip.ip()) {
                return Some(ip.ip());
            }
        }
    }

    None
}
```

**Update**
Unfortunately, adding `rustcap` did not solve this issue:

```
PS C:\Users\Richard Neumann\packet_mre> cargo add rustcap
    Updating crates.io index
      Adding rustcap v0.1.2 to dependencies.
             Features:
             - libpnet
             - pnet
PS C:\Users\Richard Neumann\packet_mre> cargo run
   Compiling memchr v2.5.0
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.66
   Compiling libc v0.2.147
   Compiling winapi v0.3.9
   Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.11
   Compiling regex-syntax v0.7.4
   Compiling no-std-net v0.6.0
   Compiling serde v1.0.183
   Compiling pkg-config v0.3.27
   Compiling pnet v0.34.0
   Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
   Compiling pnet_base v0.34.0
   Compiling pnet_macros_support v0.34.0
   Compiling pcap-sys v0.1.3
   Compiling quote v1.0.32
   Compiling aho-corasick v1.0.2
   Compiling syn v2.0.28
   Compiling regex-automata v0.3.6
   Compiling pnet_sys v0.34.0
   Compiling rustcap v0.1.2
   Compiling ipnetwork v0.20.0
   Compiling pnet_datalink v0.34.0
   Compiling regex v1.9.3
   Compiling pnet_macros v0.34.0
   Compiling pnet_packet v0.34.0
   Compiling pnet_transport v0.34.0
   Compiling packet_mre v0.1.0 (C:\Users\Richard Neumann\packet_mre)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 5.21s
     Running `target\debug\packet_mre.exe`
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to get interface list despite increasing buffer size', C:\Users\Richard Neumann\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\pnet_datalink-0.34.0\src\winpcap.rs:349:13
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\packet_mre.exe` (exit code: 101)
PS C:\Users\Richard Neumann\packet_mre>
```

Comment: You're missing a dependency https://github.com/patmarion/winpcap/tree/master Packet.lib is not a windows library but instead provided by WinPCap

Comment: Interesting. The [`pnet` docs](https://docs.rs/pnet/latest/pnet/) don't mention that one needs to include this on Windows. They just claim platform independece.

Comment: Still technically cross-platform *if* the dependencies are in place.

Comment: They do specify this in the Github readme: https://github.com/libpnet/libpnet#windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddeling with WinPCAP and `pnet` just to discover a local address turned out to be too much of a hassle. I found a solution using `ipnetwork` and `local-ip-address`:

`Cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "packet_mre"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
ipnetwork = { version = "0.20.0", default-features = false }
local-ip-address = "0.5.4"
```

`src/main.rs`

```rust
use ipnetwork::IpNetwork;
use local_ip_address::list_afinet_netifas;
use std::net::IpAddr;
use std::process::exit;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", discover_address_or_exit("172.23.56.0/24"));
}

#[must_use]
pub fn discover_address_or_exit(network: &str) -> IpAddr {
    discover_address(IpNetwork::from_str(network).unwrap_or_else(|error| {
        eprintln!("{error}");
        exit(1)
    }))
    .unwrap_or_else(|| {
        eprintln!("No address found");
        exit(2);
    })
}

#[must_use]
pub fn discover_address(network: IpNetwork) -> Option<IpAddr> {
    if let Ok(network_interfaces) = list_afinet_netifas() {
        for (_, ip) in network_interfaces {
            if network.contains(ip) {
                return Some(ip);
            }
        }
    }

    None
}
```